# how to insert OOXML data into excel and Powerpoint from an Add in

Tags: excel, ms-office, powerpoint, add-in, office-js

hey so i have a OOXML coercion type data of a ppt and excel file at present you can only insert direct OOXML data to word using office Js

[image]

i wanted to know is there a work around for opening this OOXML data in excel and powerpoint from my ADD IN ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported today in Excel or PPT. ITs a Word only feature.

Comment: is there any workaround ? like inserting to one drive and opening ?

Comment: Not with Office.js, you will have to explore a server side manipulation using the Office Open XML SDK. Would be awesome if you can share what specifically you are trying to do, and even better if you can add it to our userVoice channel https://officespdev.uservoice.com

Comment: @JuanBalmori If your offer still stands, I'd love to provide feedback. But the UserVoice forum seems abandoned.